# Show that a closed $1$-form on ${\bf R}^2 - 0$ has the form $\omega=\lambda \,d\theta+dg$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

This is Problem 4-30 from Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*:

> If $\omega$ is a $1$-form on ${\bf R}^2 - 0$ such that $d\omega = 0$, prove that
>   $$\omega = \lambda \,d\theta + dg$$
>   for some $\lambda \in {\bf R}$ and $g: {\bf R}^2 - 0 \to {\bf R}$.
>
> *Hint*: If
>   $$c_{R, 1}^* (\omega) = \lambda_R dx + d(g_R),$$
>   show that all numbers $\lambda_R$ have the same value $\lambda$.

Here, $$c_{R,1}(x)=(R\cos 2\pi x,R\sin2\pi x),$$ the superscript $^*$ denotes the pullback, and $$d\theta=-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}dx+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} dy.$$

I manage to prove the hint, but I don't know how to apply it. Please give me more direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Rearranging the first display equation motivates reframing the problem as follows:

> Show that for any $1$-form $\omega$ on $\Bbb R^2 - \{ 0 \}$ there is some constant $\mu$ such that the form
>   $$\eta := \omega - \mu \, d\theta$$
>   is exact, that is, that there is a function $f \in C^1(\Bbb R^2 - \{ 0 \})$ such that $\eta = df$.

On the other hand, the hint associates to any such $1$-form $\omega$ a constant $\lambda \in \Bbb R$.

**Remark 1** One can (and should) actually do slightly better and show that the constant $\mu$ is unique.

**Remark 2** This problem doubles as an argument that one *shouldn't* use $d \theta$ to denote the given $1$-form. Despite the notation, it is not the exterior derivative of any function on $\Bbb R^2 - \{ 0 \}$. (If it were, we could simply absorb $\lambda$ times that function into $g$, and the problem would be trivial.)

Comment: Errm, but I can't see how this lead me closer to the answer, can you please give more hint?

Comment: What conditions do you know are equivalent to exactness of a $1$-form $\eta$?

Comment: Integral path independence?

Comment: Okay, great. Do you know about the winding number of a path around $0$?

Comment: I think I get it. From previous exercise, I showed that such $g_R$ have the property that $g_R(0)=g_R(1)$. Also, we can replace the $1$ in the hint by $n$. Therefore let $\mu=\lambda/2\pi n$, $\int _{c_{R,n}}(\omega-\mu d\theta)=\int_{[0,1]}(c_{R,n}^*\omega)-\mu 2\pi n=\int_{[0,1]}(\lambda dx+dg_R)-\mu 2\pi n=\lambda-\mu 2\pi n=0$. Path independence imply exactness.

Comment: Am I correct .. ?

Comment: Yes, that's roughly the idea.